# Regular sized fonts in oubraces package

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, braces

I am using the oubraces package to get overlapping over/underbraces in an equation. My equation is in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{oubraces}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{&&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $k$-space}}&&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}}{i\hbar\frac{d\psi_n(x)}{dt}&=&-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi_n(x)}{\partial x^2}&+&\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi_n(x)&+&f(x,t)\psi_n(x)}{&&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in Hermite-Gauss basis}}&&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

The fractions are compressed to smaller than the usual display math font size. How do I restore the full sized fonts?

Comment: Try `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! (I'd give you the reputation boost for a correct answer, but I can't since it's just a comment?)

Comment: I'll add an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`

If you like, you could add some `\rule`s for increasing the vertical spacing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{oubraces}

\begin{document}
Without \verb|\rule|:
\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{&&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $k$-space}}&&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}}{i\hbar\dfrac{d\psi_n(x)}{dt}&=&-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{\partial^2\psi_n(x)}{\partial x^2}&+&\dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi_n(x)&+&f(x,t)\psi_n(x)}{&&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in Hermite-Gauss basis}}&&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}}
\end{equation}
With \verb|\rule|:
\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{&&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $k$-space}}&&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}}{i\hbar\dfrac{d\psi_n(x)}{dt}&=&\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{30pt}-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{\partial^2\psi_n(x)}{\partial x^2}&+&\dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi_n(x)&+&f(x,t)\psi_n(x)}{&&\br{3}{\text{\rule{0pt}{7pt}Diagonal in Hermite-Gauss basis}}&&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Short answer deserves a +1!

Comment: @manooooh Thank you, lol!

Answer (score 4):

You can patch `\overunderbraces` to use `\displaystyle` for the main formula when in a display environment (`equation`, `align` and so on), checking for `\if@display` that's provided by `amsmath`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{oubraces}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\overunderbraces}
  {&\hfil$}
  {&\hfil$\if@display\displaystyle\fi}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\overunderbraces}
  {&\hfil${}}
  {&\hfil$\if@display\displaystyle\fi{}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\overunderbraces{%
  &&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $k$-space}}%
  &&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}%
}{%
  i\hbar\frac{d\psi_n(x)}{dt}%
  &=%
  &-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi_n(x)}{\partial x^2}%
  &+%
  &\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi_n(x)
  &+
  &f(x,t)\psi_n(x)%
}{%
  &&\br{3}{\text{Diagonal in Hermite-Gauss basis}}%
  &&\br{1}{\text{Diagonal in $x$-space}}%
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `{-}` after the `&` in order to fix the spacing.

[image]